# Infinite primes proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, proof-explanation

There is a proof for infinite prime numbers that i don't understand.

[image]

right in the middle of the proof:
"since every such $m$ can be written in a unique way as a product of the form:
$\prod_{p\leqslant x}p^{k_p}$. we see that the last sum is equal to: $\prod_{\binom{p\leqslant x}{p\in \mathbb{P}}}(\sum_{k\leqslant 0}\frac{1}{p^k})$.

I don't see that. can anyone can explain this step to me?

Comment: It follows from the unique factorization theorem. Every $\frac{1}{n}$ has a representation as a product $\prod \frac{1}{p_i^{a_i}}$.

Comment: One should not say "infinite prime numbers" if one means "infinitely many prime numbers".  In correct usage, "infinite prime numbers" means "prime numbers, each one of which, by itself, is infinite".  If there is such a thing as an infinite prime number, then a set of six such numbers would be a set of infinite prime numbers, but _not_ of infinitely many prime numbers. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: The phrase "Everybody knows" is amusing. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Chapter 1 of the book Prime Number Records has about 22 different proofs that either (a) there is no largest prime or (b) the set of primes is infinite. There is even a topological proof. My favorite, due to  Prof. Leo Morse, is that it suffices to exhibit a strictly increasing sequence of pair-wise co-prime  natural numbers, for example the Fermat numbers.

Comment: @MichaelHardy But does everybody know that it's amusing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only the distributivity of multiplication w.r.t. addition: suppose there are $n$ primes $p_1, p_2,\dots, p_n$ less than $x$, and let's order the $m$s with only prime divisors in $\{p_1, p_2, \dots, p_n\}$ according to the lexicographical order on the $n$-uples of exponents $i_1$ of $p_1$, $i_2$ of $p_2$, &c. in the prime power decomposition of such $m$s.

For the sake of simplicity, let's consider the case when $n=2$. We then have:
\begin{align*}
\sum\frac1m=1&+\frac1{p_1}+\frac1{p_1^2}+\frac1{p_1^3}+\dotsm \\
&+\frac1{p_1p_2}+\frac1{p_1^2p_2}+\frac1{p_1^3p_2}+\dotsm\\
&+\frac1{p_1p_2^2}+\frac1{p_1^2p_2^2}+\frac1{p_1^3p_2^2}+\dotsm\\
&\ \ \vdots\\
&=\biggl(1+\frac1{p_1}+\frac1{p_1^2}+\frac1{p_1^3}+\dotsm\biggr)\biggl(1+\frac1{p_2}+\frac1{p_2^2}+\frac1{p_2^3}+\dotsm\biggr)
\end{align*}

Comment: "only the distributivity of multiplication w.r.t. addition" plus a lot of analysis fiddlework to establish this distributivity law not just for $a\left(b+c\right)$ but also for infinite products of infinite sums (assuming absolute convergence, which also needs to be proved in this specific situation).

Answer (score 5):

Suppose the prime numbers not exceeding $x$ are $2$, $3$, and $5$.  Then
\begin{align}
& \prod_{\begin{smallmatrix} p\in\mathbb P \\  p\le x \end{smallmatrix}} \sum_{k\ge 0} \frac 1 {p^k} \\[10pt] = {} & \left( 1 + \frac 1 2 + \frac 1 4 + \frac 1 8 + \cdots+ \frac 1 {2^k} + \cdots \right) \left( 1 + \frac 1 3 + \frac 1 9 + \frac 1 {27} + \cdots+ \frac 1 {3^k} + \cdots \right) \times {} \\
{} & {} \times \left( 1 + \frac 1 5 + \frac 1 {25} + \frac 1 {125} + \cdots+ \frac 1 {5^k} + \cdots \right) \tag a \\[12pt]
= {} & 1 + \frac 1 2 + \frac 1 3 + \frac 1 4 + \frac 1 5 + \frac 1 6 + \frac 1 8 + \frac 1 9 + \frac 1 {10} + \frac 1 {12} + \frac 1 {15} + \frac 1 {16} \\[6pt]
{} & {} + \frac 1 {18} + \frac 1 {20} + \frac 1 {24} + \frac 1 {25} + \frac 1 {30} + \frac 1 {32} + \frac 1 {36} + \cdots
\end{align}
In this last sum we exclude $1/7$, $1/11$, $1/13$, $1/14$, etc. and include only numbers $1/m$ where $m$ has no prime factors other than $2$, $3$, and $5$.  This last series must converge to a finite number because all three of the series in the line labeled **(a)** converge to finite numbers.

By contrast, the harmonic series $\displaystyle\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac 1 m$ diverges to $+\infty$.

Answer (score 3):

It's not *every* such $m$ that can be written as $\prod_{\substack{p\in\mathbb{P},\\ p\leq x}}\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{1}{p}$, it's that the sum of *all* such $m$ is the same as the product and summation. What your proof is saying are equal is $$\prod_{\substack{p\in\mathbb{P},\\p\leq x}}\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{1}{p}=\sum_{\substack{m \text{ with}\\ \text{prime}\\ \text{factors}\\\leq x}}\frac{1}{m}$$

For example's sake, say $x=6$. Then we're summing over $m$ with prime factors of $2$, $3$, $5$. Listing these out, we have something like

$$\prod_{p\in\{2,3,5\}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{p^k}=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{2\cdot 3}+\frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{2\cdot 5}++\frac{1}{2^2\cdot3}+\dots\text{ }.$$

Answer (score 1):

Just remember this equation:

$$\zeta(s) = \prod\left(1-\frac{1}{p^s}\right)^{-1}.$$

Where you know $\zeta(1)$ isn't convergent, so if there is a finite quantity of prime numbers, then right part is over, so there is infinite quantity of prime numbers.

Answer (score 1):

That is the "fundamental theorem of arithemetic"!
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic