# Infinite primes proof based on natural logarithm

Tags: abstract-algebra, prime-numbers, proof-explanation, prime-factorization

I'm trying to understand the proof outlined in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1594411/infinite-primes-proof?rq=1). There are related questions, **but those concern different parts of the proof.**

For completeness, here it is:

[image]

I have trouble understanding the inequality

$$1 + \frac{1}{2} + \ldots + \frac{1}{n} \leq \sum \frac{1}{m}$$

with the sum spanning over all $m\in\mathbb{N}$ which only contain prime factors that are less than $x$.

How can this be shown?

Comment: Is this from Aigner/Ziegler?

Comment: @darij grinberg It is, sorry for forgetting to cite it correctly.

Comment: All of $1,2,\ldots,n$ have only prime divisors $\leq x$ (since $n \leq x$). Thus, each addend on the left hand side is also an addend on the right hand side. There are other addends on the right hand side, but they are nonnegative, so they can only make the sum bigger.

Comment: Thank you very much. I somehow did not see that. Would you post this as an answer so I can give you the green tick?

Comment: Done. I hope the tick doesn't have the Lyme...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the numbers $1,2,\ldots,n$ are $\leq x$ (since $n \leq x$), and thus have only prime divisors $\leq x$ (since a divisor of a positive integer $m$ is always $\leq m$). Thus, each addend of the sum $\dfrac{1}{1} + \dfrac{1}{2} + \cdots + \dfrac{1}{n}$ is also an addend on the sum $\sum \dfrac{1}{m}$ which extends over all positive integers $m$ which have only prime divisors $\leq x$. The latter sum may have additional addends, but they are nonnegative, so they can only make the sum bigger. Hence, $\dfrac{1}{1} + \dfrac{1}{2} + \cdots + \dfrac{1}{n} \leq \sum \dfrac{1}{m}$.

Comment: I have recently just come across this exact proof in the book, and I can't help but wonder why they phrase it as "positive integers $m$ which have only prime divisors $ \le x$ " when the number $1$ doesn't have any prime divisors but is obviously included. Also,  you mention it may have additional addends, but wouldn't it always or is there a situation where LHS = RHS? (+1)

Comment: I don't understand your first sentence in your comment @WaveX , but LHS == RHS will happen for $x=1$ and $n=1$ (arguably not a very interesting case).

Comment: I know that we need to have $\frac{1}{1}$  as an addend of $\sum \frac{1}{m}$ to make the proof work, but the way that the book phrases the description of $\sum \frac{1}{m}$ it would seem like it shouldn't be included since $1$ doesn't meet the requirement of having a prime divisor. That's what my first sentence is about.

Comment: @WaveX: $1$ has no prime divisors, thus it has only prime divisors $\leq x$ for any value of $x$. This is by the principle of [vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).